# Gave Money to Wrong Person in Mission

Tags: hacker-experience

So I was doing a money transfer mission, and opened the internet in a new tab so that I could view the accounts and the Bank IP at the same time. After finishing it, I did another one, but I accidentally give the money to the business in the FIRST mission. Now the account I'm supposed to take money from had no money, and I don't want to abort the mission. If I give $1 to the account and send that to the business, will it count as solved? What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Send 1$ to the bank account you were suppose to transfer the money from, and quickly transfer it to the bank account the mission told you to, or you could abort the mission which would take 10% of your reputation away.